I'm trying to style my icons that are dynamicaly imported from another file.js on my react app im using react-icons
my icons are imported and stored on a separate file.js i imported the file.js on my .jsx file & i can see the svgs being rendered on my website i also can change the size but the color remains black no matter what i tried.
I'm using " react-icons/tb | react-icons/gi | react-icons/fa | react-icons/fa6 | react-icons/bi | react-icons/bs | react-icons/io5 | react-icons/md | react-icons/pi | react-icons/tb | react-icons/gi | react-icons/ai "
if anyone can help it would be much appreciated. thank you
here's my .jsx code of the icons part :
<Slider {...settings} className="categories_list">
                {categories?.slice(1, 9).map((category, index) => (
                    <Link to={`/listings/category/${category.label}`} key={index}>
                        <div className="category">
                            <img src={category.img} alt={category.label} />
                            <div className="overlay"></div>
                            <div className="category_icon">
                            {category.icon}
                                <p>{category.label}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                ))}
            </Slider>

and here is the .scss code:
&_icon {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;

        svg {
          font-size: 60px;
          color: #fff;
        }

        p {
          font-weight: 600;
          text-transform: capitalize;
          color: inherit;
        }
 } ```



I have figured it out after a long confusing time, my app.css on my react app set-up had a general rule that override's every rule i tried to set up on different scss files now it's fixed. the rule was by default *{ color= black; } Thank you.
